# Using Context API in a project I would have previously used Redux in - async action creators?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-context

So most of my projects are simple enough that Redux has been total overkill (even though it's worked really well always) - I am going to use Context API on a new project (it will easily do the job, and it's way easier to explain to other devs and get them going on) - Redux has Thunk to handle async actions. I think I understand things well enough to reason that async actions will not be a problem for Context API - Redux Thunk doesn't actually add async functionality to Redux - it simply makes the syntax more palatable. So my reasoning says that Context API will be able to handle any async actions as long as I write code to correctly deal with them. Is this right, or do I need to stick to Redux with Thunk if I want to handle async actions effectively?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar question myself and came across this article that talks about a major difference between Redux and the Context API:

From https://www.academind.com/learn/react/redux-vs-context-api/

*The Context API (currently) is not built for high-frequency updates (quote of Sebastian Markbage, React Team), it’s not optimized for that. The react-redux people ran into this problem when they tried to switch to React Context internally in their package.*

> My personal summary is that new context is ready to be used for low
>   frequency unlikely updates (like locale/theme). It’s also good to use
>   it in the same way as old context was used. I.e. for static values and
>   then propagate updates through subscriptions. It’s not ready to be
>   used as a replacement for all Flux-like state propagation. ---
>   Sebastian Markbage

*So for the moment, it seems like you might want to look into using React Context for low-frequency updates (e.g. theme changes, user authentication) but not use it for the general state management of your application.*

Hope this helps.